# Tiny Death Star Cargo Bay - Is There A Maximum Capacity?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Is there a maximum amount of items that can be kept in storage there? I have about 10 big spenders, and getting ready to earn 15 more. I like to reserve those bitizens for my Imperial court every 12hrs to earn 80K+ coins by buying out Excecution 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The cargo bay is pretty large- it will scroll down to hold more, so if you are just getting close to the first rectangular part, don't worry, there will be room for more.  If it is much beyond a couple of screens, then I don't know if there is a limit beyond that.

Using Big Spenders for massively upgraded Imperial Courts is a good way of getting coins, by the way.